# HashSet contains method for objects

Tags: java, hashset

I have a java object that has the following fields -

```
public class Fruit {    
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String color;
    private String category;
    private String description;
}
```

Now I have a set of fruits sold by vendor A, and vendor B. Both are hashsets.

```
Set<Fruit> vendorA = new HashSet<Fruit>();
Set<Fruit> vendorB = new HashSet<Fruit>();
```

I want to check in vendor A's fruits if it has a specific type of that of vendor B. In the fruit class, I've overridden hashcode and equals by the type field. I know how to use the contains method on a set. That's not my question. But if that type is present in vendor B, I need to get the fruit object of vendor B. How can I achieve this? The below part here is a pseudo code of my question -

```
for(Fruit fruits : fruit) {
    String type = fruits.getType();
    if(vendorB.contains(type)) {
        //get me the vendor B fruit object of that type
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(Fruit fruit : fruits)` is more natural than your `for(Fruit fruits : fruit)`. The loop variable is singular, and the collection is plural.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "get" method in `Set`, so you'll have to loop.

Comment: You want a Map<String, Fruit>, not a Set

Comment: You replace the `HashSet<Fruit>` with a `HashMap<String, Fruit>` where the key is the `type`. In all likelihood, you actually need a `HashMap<String, List<Fruit>>`, since there's probably more than one fruit of a given type.

Comment: How can a Set<Fruit> contain a String?

Comment: mattm of course. This is pseudo code :) @JB Nizet - Map is unfortunately not an option here :(

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Just create a map from your set, then use the map.

Comment: Because there needs to be more of one type than one.

Comment: @Cardinal if that is true (but it is not according to the OP), then all you need is a map with a list of fruits as value

Answer (score 3):

Following your approach, nest another loop.

```
for( Fruit fruitA : vendorA ) {
    String typeA = fruitA.getType() ;  // Use singular, not your plural.
    for( Fruit fruitB : vendorB ) {
        if( fruitB.getType().equals( typeA ) { … }  // We have a hit.
    }
}
```

A better way might be to implement a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Redefining `equals` as solely examining your `type` member is *not* wise if your real business scenario semantics are similar to your example here.

Comment: Yes, I did have this. But wanted to avoid nested loop :( These sets have over 600 records. But yes, I do agree it's an option, so upvoting.

Comment: Then start by creating a map of all types from `vendorB` to their respective `Fruit`, and during each loop iteration check for an entry in that map.  If you find one, use the mapped `Fruit`; otherwise, use `fruitA`.

Comment: @Basil bourque - How do I achieve this using a comparator

Comment: @rickygrimes A `Comparator` named something like `FruitTypeComparator` would let you encapsulate the fruit-to-fruit comparison logic. So this code here would not need to know about calling `getType` and doing String comparisons. With this code here as it is now, changes in your Fruit class implementation (such as using an Enum for `type` rather than a String) would break this code. A `Comparator` would make this code less brittle.

Answer (score 2):

You should reverse the problem. 
You want the intersection of A and B but fruits of B then
You loop on `vendorB` and check if each fruit is in A.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = vendorB.stream().filter(x->vendorA.contains(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You will have some problem if you use *Set*, because *Set* can have one instance of each type because you defined equals and the hashcode to this single type. Which is useful for your feature but sementically wrong. 
So you should find something.

that's why I used a *List*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a nested loop:

```
for(Fruit fruit1 : fruit) {
    String type = fruit1.getType();
    for(Fruit fruit2 : vendorB){
        if(fruit2.getType().equals(type)) return fruit2;
    }
}
//return null?
```